# Is every tricolourable knot chiral?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

In other words, can anyone give an example of a tricolourable knot that is equivalent under the Reidemeister moves to its mirror image? If not, is it known or conjectured anywhere in the literature that no tricolourable knot is equivalent under the Reidemeister moves to its mirror image?

Comment: [Square knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_knot_(mathematics)) is amphichiral and tricolorable. Perhaps for prime knots the answer is positive though.

Comment: [KnotInfo](https://knotinfo.math.indiana.edu) has lots of prime examples -- look at determinant and symmetry type, and anything with det(K) a multiple of 3 and amphichiral symmetry will work.  The first of these is 8_18.

Comment: Thank you both!